# easy-acceptor ignoring :document-root option; not serving static files

Tags: common-lisp, hunchentoot

I am trying to serve static files with Hunchentoot, from the `www` directory inside my project.  My acceptor is defined as:

```
(defvar *acceptor* (make-instance 'easy-acceptor
        :port 4242
        :document-root (truename "./www/")))
```

I then start it with:

```
(start *acceptor*)
```

The acceptor works, in that I can use `define-easy-handler` to create a root page:

```
(define-easy-handler (index :uri "/") ()
  (with-html-output-to-string (_)
      (:html
       (:head
        (:title "Hello world")
       (:body
        (:h1 "Hello world!))))))
```

... and when I browse to http://localhost:4242/ I see that page.

But no static files are served from my `www` directory.  E.g. if I create `www/jquery-3.2.1.min.js` and browse to http://localhost:4242/jquery-3.2.1.min.js I receive a 404.

```
127.0.0.1 - [2017-08-11 08:08:02] "GET /jquery-3.2.1.min.js HTTP/1.1" 404 355 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; FreeBSD amd64; rv:54.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/54.0"

HELLOWORLD> (directory (make-pathname :directory '(:relative "www") :name :wild :type "js"))
(#P"/usr/home/duncan/code/helloworld/www/jquery-3.2.1.min.js")
```

Comment: I can't seem to reproduce the problem (unless I remove permissions from the www-directory).

Comment: @jkiiski Hah!  `chmod -R 775 www` fixed it.  Thanks :)  (Happy to upvote + accept your suggestion if you make it an answer).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You must ensure that the directory and the files in it have proper permissions set. The directory needs to have the execute `x` permission to allow the server program to access the contents of the directory, and files need at least the read `r` permission.